# Изучение Java под Android

Tags: java, android, книги

Всем привет.

Меня интересует изучение Java как язык программирования для создания приложений на Android. Хочется узнать, где лучше всего изучать этот язык, в какой среде программирования начинать создавать программы.

Сразу говорю, что так же понимаю английский, так что ссылки на иностранные сайты, на которых вы учились тоже подойдут.

Если вы учили где-то Java и считаете тот источник лучшим в обучении, то, пожалуйста, киньте на него ссылку. Мне очень нужен Java для создания самых разных приложений и игр.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вот, например, пара ресурсов на великом и могучем:

http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/

http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom

Писать можно и в Eclipse (как я), но гугол с некоторых пор вовсю продвигает свою AndroidStudio, коя недавно из беты вышла.

А всё непонятное можно гуглить на [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) и тут. Причём тут, вскоре, будет официальной русскоязычной частью stackoverflow.

UPD: Вот ещё книга. Мне понравилась:

[image]

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ я знаю про AS, просто для освоения Java как язык программирования, мне кажется, она возможности не дает. Я посмотрел на AS, и если честно, то мало что в ней понял сам.

Comment: @smily_prg, я сам в неё повтыкал немного, нифига не понял, как запустить своё там приложение и забил) Сижу на эклипсе)

Comment: Пивом залил, да ?

Comment: @argamidon, боясь спровоцировать когнитивный диссонанс, всё же признаюсь, что это был даже не кофе, но чай)

Answer (score 2):

Начни с [книги](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4651265) "Программирование под Android" Брайн Харди, Билл Филлипс (2014)

Описание: Эта книга научит вас всем тонкостям разработки приложений для мобильных устройств, работающих на популярной операционной системе Android. Основанное на учебном курсе известного образовательного IT-проекта Big Nerd Ranch, это издание содержит ключевые концепции программирования в Android, разъяснение API и множество примеров кода и упражнений. В процессе работы с книгой читатель самостоятельно разработает восемь Android-приложений разной сложности и тематики, включая клиент для загрузки фотографий из базы Flickr, приложение, имитирующее телевизионный пульт дистанционного управления, а также сервис геолокации, отслеживающий перемещения пользователя по всему свету и отображающий их на карте. Все учебные приложения были спроектированы таким образом, чтобы продемонстрировать важные концепции и приемы программирования под Android и дать опыт их практического применения.

От меня: лично мне книга дала хорошую базу для начала)

P.s. Как прочитаешь, обращайся еще кое что посоветую)

Answer (score 0):

Для изучения java без обширной базы, советую эту книгу, очень необычная подача материала, ну и конечно javarush.ru
А непосредственным изучением программирования под Андроид стоит заниматься уже со знанием java core. Удачи!

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]