# Android приложение связанное с сайтом

Tags: android, мобильные-приложения

У друга есть сайт с уроками. Хотим создать android приложение которое будет уведомлять о появление новых уроков в разных разделах.У меня имеется небольшой опыт программирования на java.
 Подскажите пожалуйста, какие именно разделы нужно изучить (библиотеки и т.д), может ресурсы какие нибудь хорошие есть.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Изучение Java под Android](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/404741/%d0%98%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-java-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-android)

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего сделать приложение и в нем открыть веб браузер. Уведомления делаются через Push Уведомления.

Answer (score 0):

Как один из вариантов - Jsoup. 
Прост в использовании.